# coproduct of noncommutative algebra and commutative algebras

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

I have read the book "Rings with generalized identities" and I understand that the free product of asociative unital algebras are the coproduct of them, but I can't understand why this reduces to the tensor product of them when alegbras are conmutative.

Comment: The correct statement is that the coproduct in the category of commutative algebras is the tensor product. The coproduct of commutative algebras, in the category of noncommutative algebras, is still the free product.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, you mean that coproduct in the category of algebras (commutative or noncommutative) is the free product, right? but the category of commutative algebras is a subcategory of category of algebras, so free product should reduce to tensor product taking commutative algebras as a subcategory or I'm wrong??

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. The inclusion of a subcategory into a category need not preserve coproducts. The coproduct of two commutative algebras is two different things depending on whether you take the coproduct in the category of commutative algebras or noncommutative algebras.

Comment: aahh ok, I understand now. Thanks for you time

Answer (score 2):

The original question seems to be missing an important subtlety: the inclusion of a subcategory into a category need not preserve coproducts.

The coproduct of two commutative algebras is two different things depending on whether you take the coproduct in the category of commutative algebras or noncommutative algebras:

- The coproduct in the category of commutative algebras is the tensor product.
- The coproduct of commutative algebras, in the category of noncommutative algebras, is still the free product.

Comment: I posted this answer as CW because it's essentially just Qiaochu's comments, but this question should come off of the Unanswered queue. Please upvote or select as Best Answer to complete this process.